# Issue with Model Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have created a View Model called `CompetitionRoundModel` which is partially produced below:

```
public class CompetitionRoundModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryValues
    {
        get
        {
            return Enumerable
                .Range(0, Categories.Count())
                .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = Categories.ElementAt(x).Id.ToString(),
                    Text = Categories.ElementAt(x).Name
                });
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    // Other parameters
}
```

I have structured the model this way because I need to populate a dropdown based on the value stored in CategoryValues. So for my view I have:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, Model.CategoryValues, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    // Other code goes here
}
```

I have selected `model.CategoryId` in the `DropDownListFor()` method since I want to bind the selected value to `CategoryId`. I really don't care for `CategoryValues`, I just need it to populate the DropDown.

My problem now is that when my Controller receives the values for my Model in the action method, `CategoryValues` is null which causes the system to throw a `ArgumentNullException` (the line that is highlighted is the `return Enumerable` line.

I have even tried `[Bind(Exclude="CategoryValues")]` but no change at all. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke. Your solution worked. I just dont know how to mark your comment as an "Answer" here for you to take the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not (and should not be) creating form controls for each property of each `Category` in your `IEnumerable<Category>` collection so in your POST method, the value of `Categories` is `null` (it never gets initialized). As soon as you attempt `CategoryValues` and exception is thrown by your `.Range(0, Categories.Count())` line of code in the getter.

Change you view model to give `CategoryValues` a simple geter/setter, and delete the `Categories` property

```
public class CompetitionRoundModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryValues { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    .... // Other properties
}
```

and populate the `SelectList` in the controller methods, for example

```
var categories db.Categories; // your database call
CompetitionRoundModel model = new CompetitionRoundModel()
{
    CategoryValues = categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = x.Id.ToString(),
        Text = x.Name
    },
    ....
};
return View(model);
```

or alternatively

```
CompetitionRoundModel model = new CompetitionRoundModel()
{
    CategoryValues = new SelectList(categories, "Id", "Name" ),
```

Note also that if you return the view (because `ModelState` is invalid, the you need to repopulate the value of `CategoryValues` (refer [The ViewData item that has the key 'XXX' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) for more detail)

Answer (score 0):

Since `CategoryValues` just populates the drop down, it will never post back to the server and you'll need to rebuild the list from the database before using it in the GET or POST operation.  The `CategoryId` property is the value that will be posted back to the server from the DropDownList.